# How to override `Shipping method` in `Edit Order` area in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to override shipping method in `Edit order` area of admin side.

What I have done is , added new file

`My/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Create/Shipping/Method/Form/Form.php` in my custom module. It has code,

```
<?php
class My_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Create_Shipping_Method_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Shipping_Method_Form
{
    protected function _toHtml(){
        $this->setTemplate('module/form.phtml');
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
}
?>
```

and in my `config.xml ,`

```
<blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite><sales_order_create_shipping_method_form>My_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Create_Shipping_Method_Form</sales_order_create_shipping_method_form>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
     </blocks>
```

in `frontend/adminhtml/default/default/template/module/form.html`

I wrote

```
<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>
```

I think this is enough to override the `sales_order_create_shipping_method_form`. But Unfortunately nothing happens!!

Please let me know If i missed something.

Answer (score 0):

You have set your template as module/form.phtml and it will work but then your are calling `return parent::_toHtml()` this will override your template with parent's template.
So its better to override parent's whole method.